what 12V DC power supply should I buy?
Please help me know what 12V DC power supply to buy for my Hikvision DS-2CD2185G0-IMS camera?  (The manual was no help and I called Hikvision and they were no help.)
It has an HDMI output but while I might also connect the camera via Ethernet but my router has no PoE LAN ports.


but my router has no PoE LAN ports. ... you can buy a PoE injector ... https://duckduckgo.com/?q=PoE+injector&iax=images&ia=images
